# how to automatically change git active branch when upload files using sublime SFTP plugin?

Tags: git, sublimetext3, sftp

I have two computers,one is local client A, another computer B can be considered as a server, I use sublime and sftp plugin at A to write some code and use git as version control tool, the local git repository will deliver to B. But these are some questions.

Let's to say, these is git repository which contains two branchs: branch1 and branch2, and branch1 is the active branch. I deliver this repository to B through sublime SFTP plugin, and for some reason, I checkout the git active branch to branch2. Now, either A or B has the same git repository, the difference is the activate branch, respectively,branch1 and branc2.

And I write some new code at A's branch1, there are some several modifications at A's branch1's working area. And right now I deliver the code to B, and B's git repository is modified, but B's modification is based on branch2 becase the B's active branch is branch2.

Then the question is: if there is a solution to sync the modifications at the branch1 at B ? In other words, how to sync the branch's changing activation? The right operation may be:

write some code at A's branch1 -> deliver the code to B , when deliver the code, B's repository will automatically checkout to branch1 and then release the modifications at branch1 just like the local repository's status.

Comment: This sounds less like an SFTP question and more like a pure git question; if you want to work on projects between two computers using git and you have access to ssh, then you can just clone the repository from one machine to the other and use `git push` and `git pull` to keep things synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

With git, you can actually specify which branch you are pushing to and from. (You do not need to push from the HEAD or master branch). Here's the syntax:

```
git push <remote-name> <where you are pushing from>:<where you are pushing to>
```

Same goes for git pull. When you push and pull from branches that don't match, you may have to do some more merge work than usual, but it's definitely up to you where you push and pull to and from.